# double integral convert from cartesian to polar

Tags: polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

[image]

I have this question but I'm stuck on the integral - usually the r gets cancelled out but this time they're both r^2? I can't tell what I'm not seeing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You've done the transformation correctly:  the resulting integral is
$$I = \int_{\theta=-\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \cos \theta \, d\theta \int_{r=1}^2 r^2 \sin r^2 \, dr.$$

Although the integral with respect to $\theta$ is simply $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})/2$, the integral with respect to $r$ does not have an elementary closed form.  I suspect the author of the problem failed to realize that the Jacobian of the transformation introduces another factor of $r$.  The antiderivative can be expressed in terms of Fresnel integrals but this is not useful.  The approximate numerical value is
$$I \approx 1.1047531349442256551\ldots.$$

Comment: thank you, I was wondering if it was a typo because I was really confused and scouring the internet for a similar problem without much success.